# swiftでクラス名からインスタンスを生成する方法

Tags: objective-c, swift

swiftに関して質問です。
自作したクラスのインスタンスを生成する方法として、通常は下記のように生成できます。

```
let vc = HogeViewController()
```

ここで、自作したクラスを**HogeViewController**とした時、これを**文字列(String型)から生成する**場合にどうすればいいかわかりません。どなたかご教授頂けないでしょうか。

下記は理想なのですが、エラーになります。

```
let strVC:String = "HogeViewController"
let cls:AnyClass = NSClassFromString(strVC)
let vc:AnyObject = cls()            // この行でエラー
```

※エラー文

> ‘AnyObject’ cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers

実際に使用する場合にはクラス名の文字列は固定値ではなく、動的に変化する予定です。
よって、特定の自作クラスでキャストすることは想定していません。
コンストラクタはデフォルトを想定しています。
なお、Objective-Cの場合は下記でできます。

```
NSString* strVC = @"HogeViewController";
Class cls = NSClassFromString(strVC);
id vc = [[cls alloc] init];
```

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: [Swift で文字列からクラスを生成する方法](http://www.masaplabs.com/swift-get-class-from-string/)
これなんかどうでしょうか。 どのようなエラーが出たか分かると回答の手数が増やせるので良いかもしれません。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

以下で動作することを確認しました。
ポイントは、`@objc` をつけることと、 `class Foo : NSObject` で NSObject を継承していることです。（継承するのは NSObject から継承したクラスでも大丈夫です）

```
@objc(Foo)
class Foo : NSObject {
    func bar() {
        println("bar")
    }
}

var cls:NSObject.Type = NSClassFromString("Foo") as NSObject.Type
var foo:Foo = (cls() as Foo)
foo.bar()    // -> `bar` が出力される
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
やはり最後はasでキャストしなければいけないのでしょうか。。。
"Foo"の文字列が動的に変わることを想定しているので。

Comment: 以下は無理矢理ですがどうでしょうか。  `        var cls:NSObject.Type = NSClassFromString("Foo") as NSObject.Type
        var foo = cls()
        if foo.respondsToSelector("bar") {
            NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.0, target:foo, selector:"bar", userInfo: nil, repeats: false).fire()
        } else {
            // not support message
        }
`

Comment: 最初の質問のように API の呼び出しをせずインスタンスの作成だけでしたら以下のようにキャストは必要ありません。 `var cls:NSObject.Type = NSClassFromString("Foo") as NSObject.Type var foo = cls()`

Comment: 解決しました。インスタンスの作成部分でつまづいていました。UIViewControllerの継承クラスの場合には、UINavigationControllerにpushするときに、UIViewControllerでキャストすれば正しく目的の画面を表示できることも確認しました。
ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2):

自己解決したので、その際のコードを下記に記載します。
下記コードは「クラス名からViewControllerを生成して、UINavigationControllerにセットする」内容です。
前提として、HogeViewControllerはUIViewControllerの継承クラスで、@objc(HogeViewController)を付加していること。

```
var strVC:String = "HogeViewController"
var cls:NSObject.Type = NSClassFromString(strVC) as NSObject.Type
var vc:UIViewController = cls() as UIViewController
let navi:UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
```

上記コードのstrVCが動的に変化しても、そのクラスがロードされていれば正しく画面遷移します。

Answer (score 1):

[`NSClassFromString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-XID_36) のドキュメントの記述によると、「クラスがロードされていなければ nil となる」 と書かれており、動かないのは、クラスがロードされていないのか、指定された名前のクラスが見つからないかのどちらかだと思います。

StackOverflow のこの質問 "[NSClassFromString returns nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227085/nsclassfromstring-returns-nil)" によると、 ビルド設定の `Other Linker Flags` に、 `-ObjC` を付けることで回避ができるようです。 ただ、これのために `-ObjC` フラグを付けるのは大げさなので、同じ要領だとすると [`@objc(クラス名)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSClassFromString)を付けることでも行けると思います。要は、ObjectiveC のコードからいつでもアクセスできる状態にすればよいので。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。解決しました。
@objc(クラス名)が必要なことが良くわかりました。